# Windows 10 downloaded but not installed

Tags: windows-10

I downloaded the get windows10 app from Microsoft which is just about 7 MByte in size. I had set it up and went to do my work. The window showed 100% and then it said finishing and closing. But win10 not installed what should I do? I can't download Windows 10 again. I've win7 pro sp1

Comment: You could take a look at your Error Log, maybe you'll see the error that happened when windows tried to update. Otherwise: start cmd.exe as admin and do this `wuauclt.exe /updatenow` and monitor the update with your eyes, otherwise you won't see the error.

Comment: how can i manually install the file downloaded

Comment: Why can't you download it again and/or download the .ISO and use that?

Comment: @Dhruva `wuauclt /updatenow` will manually install the downloaded file. but make sure that the $Windows.~BT Folder exists in your C:\ drive (it's an invisible folder)

Answer (score -1):

This could mean one to many things.

1. There may not be enough space on your computer to install Windows 10
2. The program may have failed and you will have to remove all files
       related and try to download and install it again from:
       https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/windows-10-upgrade
3. You may have ran the wrong installer in which case try this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: i'm pretty sure that the files got downloaded as it showed 100% in the window(and yeah i ve the right installer and it took four hours on a 2mpb/s connection

Comment: I had the same problem and the only solution was to run it again and this time make sure you wait until you see another screen after the 100%

Comment: well tats not feasible

Comment: Stick to windows 7 then if your not bothered.... and stop posting if your not willing to try a solution